# angularJs: form validation in mg-model to consider only $modelvalue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a field in my page as amount. It is in text type and used a directive for thousand seperator. I have used ng-pattern in my input field to allow only digits and decimal points based on parameters.

```
<div ng-messages="form['amount' + index].$error">
    <div ng-message-exp="['pattern']">INVALIDVALUE</div>
 </div>
```

If I use `{{form['amount' + index].$error}}` in html, It is showing below results

> `{"$viewValue":"1,227.5","$modelValue":1227.5,"$validators":{},"$asyncValidators":{},"$parsers":[null,null],"$formatters":[null,null,null],"$viewChangeListeners":[],"$untouched":true,"$touched":false,"$pristine":true,"$dirty":false,"$valid":false,"$invalid":true,"$error":{"pattern":true},"$name":"amount0","$options":{}}`

I want to consider only $modelValue in ng-pattern.Is there any option to check this validation?

Comment: Not sure I understood, but did you try: `{{form['amount' + index].$error.$modelValue }}`

Comment: I use ng-pattern to validate field must contain digits and decimal point. But I also use thousand seperator in that field. So when i enter 12000 in input, its $viewValue is 12,000 and $modelValue is 12000. Ng-pattern is validating for digits and decimal. so 12,000 is showing invalid value

Comment: use two different inputs, one with the value you want to show(12,000) and another input hidden with value you want to use(12000)